# Regex split whilst keeping the deliminator c#

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a string like such: ***"07/04/2017 16:09:03 by Joe Bloggs) Added 07/04/2017 17:03:04 by Joe Bloggs) Updated"***

I'd like to split the string into a list of comments. The string example above contains two separate comments that I'd like to split into a list. I've identified that each new comment starts with a date. So for each date, id like to split the string.

I have attempted to use the following Regex pattern ***'\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}'*** which detects the date.

```
var sqlComments = "07/04/2017 16:09:03 by Joe Bloggs) Added 07/04/2017 17:03:04 by Joe Bloggs) Updated"
var comments = Regex.Split(sqlComments, RegexDateIdentifier);
return comments.Where(c => c != string.Empty).ToList();
```

However the code above, splits the string as I'd like, but removes the date. So I am left with like;

1. 16:09:03 by Joe Bloggs) Added
2. 17:03:04 by Joe Bloggs) Updated

Can anyone advise how to perform the above but with keeping the date (the deliminator)?

Comment: Have a search around for info on lookahead assertions - they should help you split on "space that's followed by a date" which looks like what you want. It's also worth checking that you date format won't change (e.g. to ISO 8601 format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are after, it uses a [Zero-Width Positive Lookahead Assertion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion) plus a `\s+` to remove the spaces:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string RegexDateIdentifier = @"\s+(?=\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})";
        var sqlComments = "07/04/2017 16:09:03 by Joe Bloggs) Added 07/04/2017 17:03:04 by Joe Bloggs) Updated";
        var comments = Regex.Split(sqlComments, RegexDateIdentifier);
        var list = comments.ToList();

        foreach (var s in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("|{0}|", s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That did the job!